# The element of Volume of the Sphere and two formulas

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $S^{n-1}$    be the unit sphere  with the inner product $<.,.>$ that inherits from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\in S^{n-1}$. Let $\{e_ i \}_{ i=1}^n $  be an orthonormal frame and let $<V,e_i>=v_i$ . Let $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ be an element of volume on $S^{n-1}$.

1.
 For $i\not =j\ $,
  $\int_{S^{n-1}}v_iv_j \ \mathrm{d}\sigma(V)=0$ , since the integrand is odd with respect to reflection about the coordinate hyperplane $\{v_i =0\}$ .

I do not understand this reason. How can I find out it?

2.
  $ \ \int_{S^{n-1}}v_i^2 \ \mathrm{d}\sigma(V)= \ \int_{S^{n-1}}v_j^2 \ \mathrm{d}\sigma(V)$ .  Why?

Comment: Where did this problem arise? It seems that the setup is unnecessarily complicated. You could ask the question of $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$; your question makes no real reference to $M$.

Comment: @Michael Albanese;  You are right. Of course, I know that $T_pM$ and $\mathrm{R}^n$ are isomorph. Now, How can I prove these formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you know that problem lies in tangent space at a single point. Let's recall one fact.

> If $\phi:M_1\rightarrow M_2$  is a diffeomorphism between two manifolds and $\omega$ is a top degree form on $M_2,$ then
>   $$\int_{M_2}\omega=\int_{M_1}\phi^*(\omega).$$

To answer the first problem we let $\phi:S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ to be a reflection by $\{V_i=0\},$ which is given by the formula
$$\phi(V)=V-2v_i e_i.$$
It is linear, hence it's derivative $\phi_*$ is equal to $\phi$ and for volume form $d\sigma$ on $S^{n-1}$ we have
$$\phi^*(d\sigma)(X_2,\dots,X_n)=(d\sigma)(X_2,\dots,X_n)-2(d\sigma)((X_2)_ie_i,\dots,(X_n)_ie_i)=(d\sigma)(X_2,\dots,X_n).$$
We see that $\phi^*(d\sigma)=d\sigma.$
Now we can use the mentioned fact.
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}v_iv_jd\sigma(V)=\int_{S^{n-1}}\phi^*(v_iv_jd\sigma(V))=\int_{S^{n-1}}(\pi_i\pi_j)(\phi(V)) d\sigma(V)=\int_{S^{n-1}}(v_i-2v_i)(v_j-0)d\sigma(V)=-\int_{S^{n-1}}v_iv_jd\sigma(V).$$
Hence
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}v_iv_jd\sigma(V)=0.$$
To proof second problem we use similar trick, but instead of refflection we use rotation. We just proof that
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}v_i^2d\sigma=\int_{S^{n-1}}v_j^2d\sigma.$$
But first recall another fact.

> If $\omega$ is a volume form on $M$ and $S$ is a submanifold of codimention 1 with specified outward normal vector field $N$ then the volume form in $S$ is equal to $i_N\omega,$ where $i_N$ is an interior product.

Set $\phi:S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ to be a rotation that sends $e_j$ to $e_i.$ Rotation is linear. Hence $\phi^*(d\sigma)(X_2,\dots,X_n)=i_N\omega(\phi X_2,\dots,\phi X_n)=\omega(\phi N,\phi X_2,\dots,\phi X_n).$ Last equality holds, because pullback "pushes" points. So for every $x\in S^{n-1}$ vector $N$ is taken at $N_{\phi(x)}=\phi N.$ Returning to $\omega(\phi N,\phi X_2,\dots,\phi X_n),$ we have
$$\omega(\phi N,\phi X_2,\dots,\phi X_n)=\det(\phi)\omega(N,X_2,\dots,X_n)=i_N\omega(X_2,\dots,X_n)=d\sigma(X_2,\dots,X_n).$$ Again using first fact we have that
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}v_i^2 d\sigma(V)=\int_{S^{n-1}}\phi^*(v_i^2 d\sigma(V))=\int_{S^{n-1}}\pi_i^2(\phi(V)) d\sigma(V)=\int_{S^{n-1}}v_j^2 d\sigma(V).$$

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer. But I have some question about it. 1. Why ![first question?](http://i57.tinypic.com/2z9e79x.jpg) and what is rotation rule for $\varphi$ ? and why ![second question?](http://i57.tinypic.com/wln28.jpg)

Comment: And But why ![Third question?](http://i60.tinypic.com/mbigsj.jpg)

Comment: First: 2(dσ)((X2)iei,…,(Xn)iei) disappear, because volume form is screw simmetric and (Xr)iei and (Xs)iei are lineary dependent.
Second: First equality holds just by definition of interior product and the second fact mentioned as quote (set M to be R^n and S to be S^{n-1}). I expalind second equality, in answer, but let me expand it. Pullback at point x of $\omega$ by $\phi$ is equal to $\omega(\phi(x))$. So if you place N in the first place you get $\phi N.$
Third: Second equality holds by the fact that $\phi$ is element of SO(n,R).

Comment: 4. Is your mean $N_φ(x)=φ_∗N$ ? and since $φ=φ_∗$ then $N_{φ(x)}=φN$

Comment: I understand all of them except the following equality: 5. Why $ φ∗(dσ)(X_2,X_3,⋯,X_n)=i_Nω(φX_2,⋯,φX_n)$ ?  6.  What is the rule of φ (rotation)?  7. What is your reference for your second fact?

Comment: My principal question: What is rule of rotation($\varphi$)? Why do rotation take the volume form to volume form? i.e. why $φ^∗(dσ)(X_2,⋯,X_n)=\text{a volume form on} S^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: 4. No. You don't have to push N by $\phi.$ Just $N_{\phi(x)}=(\phi(N))_x.$
5. It is the same reasoning as with reflection. Rotation is liner, hence $\phi_*=\phi.$
6. Do you want exactly formula?
7. I just admire Lee's books. So it would be his book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds 2000, Prop. 10.37, p.260."
Ps. In fact I forget to mention that $M$ has to be riemannian, but in our case we have the inner product of $T_p M$ (this $M$ is different, it is one from your original question).

Comment: I found that  with $ϕ(V)=V−2v_ie_i$ we have $ϕ^∗(dσ)(X_2,…,X_n)=(dσ)(X_2,…,X_n)−2(dσ)$.                                                                                                        But I do not understand that  why                         $φ^∗(dσ)(X_2,⋯,X_n)=i_Nω(φX_2,⋯,φX_n)$.  What is the rule of $\varphi$ (rotation) exactly? and why $φ^∗(dσ)(X_2,⋯,X_n)= \text{a volume form on} S^{n−1}$ ?

Comment: The clue lies in the two facts about rotation. That $\phi$ is linear and it is an element of the special orthogonal group $SO(n,\mathbb{R}).$ By linearity $\phi_*=\phi$ and then by definition of pullback $φ^*(d\sigma)(X_2,\dots,X_n)=d\sigma(\phi X_2,\dots,\phi X_n).$ And then by the second fact mentioned in answer it is equal to $i_N\omega(\phi X_2,\dots,\phi X_n).$

Comment: Be careful: Your first equation holds if and only if $\phi$ is orientation-preserving. You didn't make reference to $M_1$ and $M_2$ being oriented manifolds, but you really need to do so in order to have the integral defined.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, You are right. Where can I find a  reference for proving of the first fact ? Which book?

Comment: @bigli: Any standard source on integration on manifolds. It is a consequence of the change of variables theorem on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Which book? Ps. What is $\pi_i(\phi(V))=?$ as $\phi$ is the rotation?

Comment: Munkres, *Analysis on Manifolds*, for example. Actually @FallenApart's answer is wrong. A reflection is orientation-*reversing* and so you pick up a minus sign in the integral. Rotations are, however, orientation-*preserving*.

Comment: You are right. I do not attend it. Now, What can I do? Ps. What is $π_i(ϕ(V))=$? as $ϕ$ be a rotation on $\mathbb R^n$ that sends $e_j$ to $e_i$ ?

Comment: @Fallen Apart: 1. reflection about the coordinate hyperplane  $\{v_i=0\}$ is $\phi(V)=V-2<V,e_i^{\perp}>e_i^{\perp}$ and your formula for the reflection is wrong.   2. $ϕ^∗(dσ)(X_2,…,X_n)=(dσ)(X_2,…,X_n)−2(dσ)((X_2)_ie_i,…,(X_n)_ie_i)$ is wrong certainly. If you check them , you see.